# How can i Show user Data fromFirestore in my Designed Profile Page?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saUdM.png)hi iam new to flutterxfirebase
i sign up a user
and design a profile page, i want to show curent user information
email,phone number,location..

```
Future data (String firstName, String lastName, int year, int month,
  int day, String email, String password) async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
  'first name': firstName,
  'last name': lastName,
  'yesr': year,
  'month': month,
  'day': day,
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
});}
```

i searched alot but cant get it , how it works , so if you can show me where to start i can get the rest ,thanks

Comment: What does your saved data look like in firebase? You can get the data of a particular user with id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these methods...

### 1. Using a custom user ID.

```dart
final String userId = _generateUserId();
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId);

// Store the user's data
await userRef.set(data);

// Fetch the user's data.
final DocumentSnapshot userData = userRef.get();
```

### 2. Using the resulting document snapshot.

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .add(data);

final String documentId = userDoc.id;

// Fetch the user's data using the document ID.
final DocumentSnapshot userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(documentId)
  .get();
```